# How to align variables by type and one space/tab in Java with Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, alignment

I need alignment by the typename and one space/tab character after it using auto-format. Is it possible?

In other words I want it

```
int i = 0,
        j12 = 0,
        k123 = 0;

String str1,
        string2;

StringBuilder sb1,
        longNameStringBuilder;
```

to look like this:

```
int i1   = 0,
    j12  = 0,
    k123 = 0;

String str1,
       string2;

StringBuilder sb1,
              longNameStringBuilder;
```

Comment: Quick question: why not one declaration per line, each line ending with a `;`? The same-length type will align the attributes/parameters automatically in a neat way.

Comment: This isn't implemented.

Comment: @Turing85 I need it for olymp programming, so I need to type fast. And this is just the style I prefer from other languages.

Comment: @LevS. I've seen your upvote. I'll describe the wanted result for you on the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, this isn't currently possible.
However you can upvote and comment with your requirement on the below issue.
They're are usually eager to solve this kind of problems, but a couple upvotes are always better.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-170399